# Global Exception Handling for winforms control

Tags: winforms, error-handling, user-controls

When working on ASP.NET 1.1 projects I always used the Global.asax to catch all errors. I'm looking for a similar way to catch all exceptions in a Windows Forms user control, which ends up being a hosted IE control. What is the proper way to go about doing something like this?

Comment: Also have a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944/unhandled-exception-handler-in-net-11) for some of the pitfalls (links to a couple of coding horror blog entries).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to handle the `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException` event for Windows Forms. This article really helped me: http://bytes.com/forum/thread236199.html.

Answer (score 11):

Currently in my winforms app I have handlers for `Application.ThreadException`, as above, but also `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

Most exceptions arrive via the `ThreadException` handler, but the AppDomain  has also caught a few in my experience

Comment: Sample code from MSDN showing how to catch both types of unhandled exceptions: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using VB.NET, you can tap into the very convenient ApplicationEvents.vb.  This file comes for free with a VB.NET WinForms project and contains a method for handling [unhandled exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a02k5s0(VS.80).aspx).

To get to this nifty file, it's "Project Properties >> Application >> Application Events"

If you're not using VB.NET, then yeah, it's handling [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

To Handle Exceptions Globally...

**Windows Application**

System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException event

*Generally Used in Main Method. Refer [MSDN Thread Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)*

**Asp.Net**

System.Web.HttpApplication.Error event

*Normally Used in Global.asax file. Refer [MSDN Global.asax Global Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3(v=vs.140).aspx)*

**Console Application**

System.AppDomain.UnhandledException event

*Generally used in Main Method. Refer [MSDN UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)*

Answer (score 2):

Code from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

```
Sub Main()
  Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
  AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyHandler

  Try 
     Throw New Exception("1")
  Catch e As Exception
     Console.WriteLine("Catch clause caught : " + e.Message)
     Console.WriteLine()
  End Try 

  Throw New Exception("2")
End Sub 

Sub MyHandler(sender As Object, args As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
  Dim e As Exception = DirectCast(args.ExceptionObject, Exception)
  Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message)
  Console.WriteLine("Runtime terminating: {0}", args.IsTerminating)
End Sub
```