# Systray Application Exiting

Tags: c#, windows, icons, system-tray

I have a small, simple C# application which updates an icon in the system tray. I use it to graphically show the CPU usage. The application works great. I keep the Window hidden and don't show it in the taskbar so it doesn't get in the way.

My issue is that it will run great for a while. Often several hours. But then it will mysteriously quit. No warnings. Nothing. The icon is just gone and the program is no longer running. I have tested the program in the debugger under varying conditions, so I don't think that is it. Is there something obvious I am missing? If the program encounters an error and quits should I be expecting a message if the Form is hidden? Is there some "keep-alive" message or something that I need to handle?

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    trayIcon.Text = "CPU Utilization";
    trayIcon.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40);

    trayIcon.Visible = true;

    update = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateCPU));
    update.Start();
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    Visible = false;
    ShowInTaskbar = false;

    base.OnLoad(e);
}

private void UpdateCPU()
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(32, 32);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);

    while (true)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(c3), 17, 17, 15, 15);
        trayIcon.Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(bm.GetHicon());

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the Event Viewer system tool and look for the error log for your application. Maybe there's a crash report or a warning. Second thing - check the Task Manager and see if your process allocates too much memory. I understand there's a GC and stuff but the Icon.FromHandle() call looks suspicious.

Comment: Not to be sarcastic, but are you *sure* it's terminated and not just hidden by Microsoft's auto-hide systray icons functionality?

Comment: The system wasn't totally out of memory, if that's what you meant. It was only using 1 GB / 8 GB. I have implemented Sean's suggestion to fix the FromHandle() issue anyway though.

Comment: And yes, I'm sure it was terminated. I double-checked the auto-hide first thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you add an Unhandled Exception Handler

[Global Exception Handling for winforms control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770/global-exception-handling-for-winforms-control)

An Exception is likely being thrown, causing your program to exit.

Then, introduce logging to log what the Exception was.  Personally I prefer [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).

I'm a bit surprised that you can update trayIcon from a non-UI thread without receiving a cross-thread exception.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about whether or not to use the UI thread, and I know that cross-threading can give inconsistent results. I'll try running it without threads and see if that works.

Comment: Rather than run without threads, just use a delegate to update your UI thread.  See the following link for a most excellent extension method that makes invoking on the UI thread from another thread a real breeze: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3588137/141172

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle.aspx) seems to agree with Viktor Latypov's comment, you should be doing something like this:

```
Icon newIcon = Icon.FromHandle(bm.GetHicon());

trayIcon.Icon = newIcon;

DestroyIcon(newIcon.Handle);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented this as well. I'll try running it for a while and see if it fixes the issue.