# Tracking Crash in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm programming a batch printer, but it crashes randomly during the print, saying "XXX has stop working", nothing more than that. How do I track the crash and get more information?

I added `try` and `catch` but it never goes to catch bracket.

Code:

```
    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (parts == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        ultraGrid1.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.ExitEditMode);
        foreach (Part part in parts)
        {
            if (part.Selected)
            {
                switch (part.FileType)
                {
                    case "PDF":
                        //SendToPDFReaderPrinter(part);
                        break;
                    case "SLDDRW":
                        if (!useSolidworksToPrint)
                        {
                            SendToeDrawingsPrinter(part);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //SendToSolidworksPrinter(part);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Print Complete.");
    }

    private void SendToeDrawingsPrinter(Part part)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = part.FilePath;
            //Show Preview
            axAcroPDF1.Hide();
            eDrawingControl1.Show();
            //Load file
            eDrawingControl1.eDrawingControlWrapper.OpenDoc(filePath, false, false, false, "");
            //Config
            eDrawingControl1.eDrawingControlWrapper.SetPageSetupOptions(EModelView.EMVPrintOrientation.eLandscape, 1, 0, 0, 1, 7, printerName, 1, 1, 1, 1);
            //Print  
            Wait(2);  //Wait for 2 seconds
            eDrawingControl1.eDrawingControlWrapper.Print4(false, filePath, false, false, true, EModelView.EMVPrintType.eScaleToFit, 1, 0, 0, true, 1, 1);
            Wait(2);  //Wait for 2 seconds
            //eDrawingControl1.eDrawingControlWrapper.CloseActiveDoc("");
            //Hightligh Printed Row
            HighlightPrintedRow(part, true);
        }
        catch
        {
            HighlightPrintedRow(part, false);
        }
    }

    //Wait
    private void Wait(double seconds)
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        while (start.AddSeconds(seconds) >= DateTime.Now)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }

    private void HighlightPrintedRow(Part part, bool isSuccessful)
    {
        foreach (var row in ultraGrid1.Rows)
        {
            if ((Part)row.ListObject == part)
            {
                row.Appearance.BackColor = (isSuccessful ? Color.LightGreen : Color.Red);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does that happen when running under the debugger? Do you set it to stop when exceptions are thrown?

Comment: Have you stepped through to narrow down the line on which it occurs?

Comment: Thanks, I will try enabling "break when exceptions are thrown" @RowlandShaw

Comment: Nothing goes wrong when step through...@DonBoitnott

Comment: When I try to debug, no exception is thrown, I got a "vshost.exe" has sttpped working" error

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see which line the application stops working on?

Comment: What is the target version of .NET? For .NET 4+ the CLR does not allow the process to handle [corrupted state exceptions](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/All-about-Corrupted-State-Exceptions-in-NET4.aspx). This could be an exception thrown by unmanaged code: in your project properties enable unmanaged code debugging. Also, if you include the code for `HighlightPrintedRow` you may help us help you.

Comment: If your error is tied to assembly loading error, it won't help much, but you could be interested by handling AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and  Application.ThreadException events. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770/global-exception-handling-for-winforms-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to have a look at the system's *Event Viewer*. Usually you will find something there if you get 'xxx stops working' for .NET applications.

Or, you can use a low-level bug tracking component to catch all exception even from the .NET runtime. See [BugTrap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14618/Catch-All-Bugs-with-BugTrap)

Comment: Faulting application name: bruno_batchprint.vshost.exe, version: 12.0.21005.1, time stamp: 0x524fac12
Faulting module name: EModelView.dll, version: 15.0.0.5013, time stamp: 0x5429b603
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000a9c68
Faulting process id: 0x2b84
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1007ba16d0b38
Faulting application path: D:\Projects\brumo_batch_print_excel\bruno_batchprint\bin\Debug\bruno_batchprint.vshost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\eDrawings X64 Edition\EModelView.dll
Report Id: f2556ebe-6c70-11e5-b85d-c0389642987a

Comment: I guess this means the error occurs in  "EModelView.dll" ? How do I know whether it is caused by the dll 's internal error or because I've used it in an improper way?

Comment: Yes, it is the fault from that component. You may need to ask the supporting team of that component. Or you can still try to use BugTrap and see if it can tell you more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Switching to Managed Compatibility Mode in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Sometimes a VS restart or reboot helps.