# Need to handle exception on image resizer

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer

Reviewing my log find this exception, but can't figure out how it should be fixed, any ideas?

```
ImageResizer.ImageProcessingException (0x80004005): Image Resizer: No image encoder was found for the request.
   в ImageResizer.InterceptModule.HandleRequest(HttpContext context, String virtualPath, NameValueCollection queryString, IVirtualFile vf)
   в ImageResizer.InterceptModule.CheckRequest_PostAuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   в System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   в System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

And if there such place in the configuration where I can listen exception and handle them properly. It's installed as a HttpModule and can figure how to handle exceptions globally.

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer selects an encoder based on the `&format=` querystring value.

The most common cause of this error is a typo, say requesting `image.jpg?format=jif` instead of `image.jpg?format=gif`.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I never use such query string (&format=).  Is there place in the configuration of ImageResizer or sub to Event to listen exceptions and handle them properly.

Comment: That doesn't mean one of your visitors or a robot hasn't. ImageResizer throws ImageProcessingExceptions so you can identify them - how you handle unhandled app exceptions is up to you.

Comment: It's actually developers internal nonindex site, it used by marketing people. I don't think that people can do this explicitly. Can you please provide some code sample, how I can catch this in ImageResizer? I would really appreciate this.

Comment: See [How to catch unhandled exceptions in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295731/easy-way-to-catch-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-c-net).